# Python: Write content to an open stream

Tags: python, file, stream

I am working with an API that takes an open binary file as a parameter and then performs blocking reads on that until EOF.

Rather than opening an existing file (io.open mode 'rb') I want to pass it a stream that I write calculated/constructed content to - in effect I want something that is conceptually a unidirectional pipe where the output is delivered via an inputstream that is interchangeable with an open file.

I looked at BufferedRWPair but the few examples I could find all violate it's warnings not to use the same object for the input and output sides.

If anyone has an appropriate example or better suggestion, it's welcome!

I've looked at BufferedRandom based on comments here, but I'm obviously doing something wrong as....

    `import io
    buf = io.BufferedRandom(io.BytesIO())
    buf.write("a")
    buf.write("b")
    buf.flush()
    while True:
        print "reading"
        a = buf.read(1024)
        if not a: break
        print "read: {}".format(a)
    buf.close()`

This exits after the first read

**update**
This admittedly messy example shows the solution, having to maintain independent read and write positions

```
import io
buf = io.BufferedRandom(io.BytesIO())
read = 0
wrote = 0
buf.seek(wrote)
wrote += buf.write(b"a")
wrote += buf.write(b"b")
buf.seek(read)
data = buf.read(1)
read += len(data)
buf.seek(wrote)
wrote += buf.write(b"c")
print "read: {}".format(data)
buf.seek(read)
data = buf.read(512)
read += len(data)
wrote += buf.write(b"d")

buf.seek(wrote)
wrote += buf.write(b"efghihjlmnop")
while data:
    print "read: {}".format(data)
    buf.seek(read)
    data = buf.read(1024)
    read += len(data)
buf.close()
```

Comment: Read about: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.BufferedRandom

Comment: Not quite as it does not seem to allow me to interleave reads and writes to the stream without (I guess) managing the current read and write positions myself.  I guess that's a natural consequence of having the same stream. Is that expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... allow me to interleave reads and writes to the stream without ... managing the current read and write positions myself.

This is the behave of `io.BufferedRandom`.
But you can encapsulate the logic into a own `class StreamRW(io.BufferedRandom)`,
for instance:

```
class StreamRW(io.BufferedRandom):
    def __init__(self, raw):
        super().__init__(raw)
        self.seek(0)

    def read(self, size=1):
        super().seek(self.read_offset)
        data = super().read(size)
        self.read_offset = self.tell()
        return data

    def write(self, data):
        super().seek(self.write_offset)
        written = super().write(data)
        self.write_offset = self.tell()
        return written

    def seek(self, offset):
        super().seek(offset)
        self.read_offset = self.write_offset = self.tell()

#Usage:
buf = StreamRW(io.BytesIO())
...
```

**Further code as below, but without `buf.seek(0)`**!

---

You have to use `buf.seek(0)` to rewind the file position.
**Note**: I have to use `binary prefix b""`!
This is working for me:

```
import io
buf = io.BufferedRandom(io.BytesIO())
buf.write(b"a")
buf.write(b"b")
buf.seek(0)

while True:
    print "reading"
    a = buf.read(1024)
    if not a: break
    print "read: {}".format(a)
buf.close()
```

> **Output**:
>   read: b'ab'

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: Not quite as it does not seem to allow me to interleave reads and writes to the stream without (I guess) managing the current read and write positions myself. I guess that's a natural consequence of having the same stream. Is that expected?

Comment: Thanks much! that's a much less messy version of the answer I posted, but I see that it probably works if I pass an instance of this new derived class as the stream that's currently taking the input file.  This does sound like the purpose of BufferedRWPair which I am still unable to get to work, and I'll go with your suggested approach.

Comment: @user9548: Read What should I do when someone answers my question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers